# i want to update paypal subscription (HTML Payments Standard Subscriptions/classic mathod)

Tags: django, paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-subscriptions

i have implement subscription using this link :
https://overiq.com/django-paypal-integration-with-django-paypal/

this mathod is using classic/old subscription technique i guess

i used this method to get paypal form to subscribe

```
def processSubscriptionPaypal(userRequest,price,billing_cycle,billing_cycle_unit,successUrl,cancelUrl,metadata):
    try:
        host = userRequest.get_host()
        host2 = userRequest.get_host() #for paypal-ipn url
        print('http://{}{}'.format(host2,
                                    '/settings/paypal/'))

        paypal_dict  = {
            "cmd": "_xclick-subscriptions",
            'business': settings.PAYPAL_RECEIVER_EMAIL_2,
            "a3": price,  # monthly price
            "p3": billing_cycle,  # duration of each unit (depends on unit)
            "t3": billing_cycle_unit,  # duration unit ("M for Month")
            "src": "1",  # make payments recur
            "sra": "1",  # reattempt payment on payment error
            "no_note": "1",  # remove extra notes (optional)
            'item_name': 'Content subscription test yo2',
            # 'custom': {"userId":"1","planId":"2","storeId":"1"},     # custom data, pass something meaningful here
            'custom': metadata,     # custom data, pass something meaningful here
            'currency_code': 'USD',
            'notify_url': 'http://{}{}'.format(host2,
                                    '/settings/paypal/'),
            # 'notify_url': 'http://{}{}'.format(host,
            #                                 reverse('paypal-ipn')),
            'return_url': successUrl,
            'cancel_return': cancelUrl,
        }

        form = PayPalPaymentsForm(initial=paypal_dict, 
               button_type="subscribe")

        return form
    except Exception as e:
        
        print("something went wrong in processSubscriptionPaypal/n",e)
        return False
```

now i want to update the exising subscription,
i show the paypal documentation but this is the another mathod to integrate paypal, and i had integrate paypal only using email,

i think this is the classic subscription using paypal, and i can not found any official docs for subscription for paypal with this mathod,

so how to update subscription with this mathod?

also if anyone find any official docs please share

thanks in advance !!

Comment: IPN does not create transactions. It is not a payment nor subscription integration method. It only notifies of completed payments (and is a very old way of accomplishing that). If you have questions about "updating" a subscription, you'll need to start by explaining what sort of subscription this is. IPN is not an answer.

Comment: To be clear, there are at least 5 different ways of processing subscriptions with PayPal, if you count classic/old integrations. None of them are called IPN.

Comment: @PrestonPHX can you give me official docs link for this type of method usid in this link : https://overiq.com/django-paypal-integration-with-django-paypal/  i want to update and delete subscription but this website dont include them, it will be great help

Comment: @PrestonPHX i have updated my question about how i am implementing subscription, it will give me form with button to create subscription

Answer (score 1):

You're using [HTML Payments Standard Subscriptions](https://developer.paypal.com/api/nvp-soap/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/subscribe-step-1/). Functionality is very limited, since there are no API calls with this integration.

If changes need to be made, have users cancel their existing subscription and re-subscribe with the new terms.